# The best way to share types in a large TypeScript project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm working on a large React application written on TypeScript. I have many common types declared in separate files, and every time I need a type I import it. It works well, but creates tons of different imports, what I definitely don't like.

Another option would be to use .d.ts files to declare types globally and be able to use types without explicitly importing them. Is this considered as a better practice or I should stay with imports?

Comment: If i'm working with typescript directly I usually would not create a .d.ts file, but if you have shared Types, you could maybe move them to a separate file, as rdd mentions in his answer. If you where to compile it, typescript has the options to generate a .d.ts files automatically

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think a common sense approach to this is the best. For example, we are working in a large React app right now, using a monorepo, with a shared repository for shared components. So we have rules about things like declarations and components:

- if you use a type/interface in more than one place it goes into the ~shared/lib/types.ts file
- if you have a component that's used in more than one place it gets refactored to to the ~shared/components folder
- if you extend a type/interface, it can be declared locally, but as long as it doesn't get used more than once

Once people get used to these simple rules, it begins to make development work a lot easier. Devs get used to refactoring when they need to, but also about thinking about how they code.

Comment: +1 This is a good approach, we do something similar with a large Angular app we are currently developing and maintaining!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Though regarding imports, do you think it's okay to explicitly import shared types in every file/modules which uses them? I could use .d.ts files to declare types globally and use across the project without imports at all.

Comment: I don't think there's a problem with it, you are specifically saying what you want. Moving those imports into a single file to import only cleans up our view of it, the code still imports them.

Comment: I am interested in knowing how you guys deal with a component that has a large set of types defined which end making the file difficult to read and focusing on the code logic rather than its types? The types are directly related to the component and only sometimes imported elsewhere for the component consumption? What would be the best approach in this situation? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

1. Put all the shared declarations in a file, say index.d.ts.
2. Put this file in a folder say /src/typings
3. In tsconfig.json, update the following field:

   ```
   {.   
      "compilerOptions": {.  
          "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./src/typings"].  
      }.  
   }.
   ```

Now the types will be available in all files.